# Facebook custom conversion inactive

Tags: ads, facebook-ads

I created a custom conversion event in Facebook with the following set up:

[image]

So basically what I want to track is when someone goes to the registration page of my site and gets redirected after registration to the "member/dashboard" page. So for a successful conversion both rule must be fulfilled.

I tried several test registrations, but the custom conversion is still inactive on my account. The pixel is installed properly because other events and conversions work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the set up you have, it looks like you have URL = register and URL = member/dashboard at the same time. Facebook will not recognize this configuration as a visit first and then a redirected website.

One other possible way to capture your conversion of registrations being completed is to edit your pixel code and use the standard event "Complete registration" with the standard event code

`fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');`

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/402791146561655?id=1205376682832142
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/conversion-tracking